# Using least independent rectangle area to separate every point

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization

### Description

I want to add vertical line and horizonal lines between data to make every point have an independent rectangle area. In addtion, every independent rectangle has a number $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$

### Algorithm

I have a method that adds a line between two points to separate them. However, it will yield many rectangles`(as the Kuba's answer shows)`. So I add a condition that *if the coordinate difference of two adjacent points is less than Δ, the line between them will be deleted.* Using this condition to reduce the number of rectangles.

The ideal result would appear as shown below:

[image]

### My method for use with a large data set

***Function GridLineData*** (yield the coordinate of line that between two points)

```
GridLineData[data_List, Δ_] := Block[
 {sortData, length, OriginData, deleteData},
  sortData = DeleteDuplicates@(Sort@data);
  length = Length@sortData;
  OriginData =
    Append[
      Prepend[sortData, 2 sortData[[1]] - sortData[[2]]],
     2 sortData[[length]] - sortData[[length - 1]]];
  deleteData =
     List /@ (First /@ Select[
     Thread[List[Range[length - 1], Differences@sortData]],
    #[[2]] < Δ &]) + 1;
  Delete[Total@#/2 & /@ Partition[OriginData, 2, 1], deleteData]
]
```

***Function GridNumber*** (yield the number that in one direction of point)

```
GridNumber[data_List, Δ_] := Block[
   {length, intervalData},
   length = Length@GridLineData[data, Δ] - 1;
   intervalData = 
   Interval /@ (Partition[GridLineData[data, Δ], 2, 1]);
   First@Pick[Range@length, IntervalMemberQ[intervalData, #]] & /@ data
]
```

***Function Grid2DNumber***(yield the number that in two directions of point)

```
Grid2DNumber[data_List, Δx_, Δy_] := Block[
 {xGridNumber, yGridNumber},
  xGridNumber = GridNumber[data[[All, 1]], Δx];
  yGridNumber = GridNumber[data[[All, 2]], Δy];
  Thread[List[xGridNumber, yGridNumber]]
]
```

***Function FinalNumber*** (yield the number of point )

```
FinalNumber[data_List, Δx_, Δy_] := Block[
 {length},
  length = Length@GridLineData[data[[All, 1]], Δx] - 1;
 (#[[2]] - 1) length + #[[1]] & /@ 
  Grid2DNumber[data, Δx, Δy]
]
```

***Function ResultShow***

```
  ResultShow[data_List, Δx_, Δy_,imageSize_, plotRange_, axes_] := Block[ 
  {xGridLineData, yGridLineData},
  xGridLineData = GridLineData[data[[All, 1]], Δx];
  yGridLineData = GridLineData[data[[All, 2]], Δy];
  ListPlot[
      data, GridLines -> {xGridLineData, yGridLineData},
      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], Axes -> axes,
      AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.02], ImageSize -> imageSize, 
      PlotRange -> plotRange,
      AxesLabel -> (Style[#, FontFamily -> Times, 15, Italic] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
      Epilog -> Style[Text @@@Thread[List[ FinalNumber[data, Δx, Δy], data]], Pink] 
    ]
 ]
```

**Running**

```
  data= {{0.028, 0.}, {-0.02, 0.}, {0.024, 0.}, {0.02, 0.}, {0.016, 0.}, {0.012, 0.},
    {0.008, 0.}, {0.004, 0.}, {0., 0.}, {-0.004,  0.}, {-0.008, 0.}, {-0.012, 0.}, 
    {-0.016, 0.}, {-0.02, 0.01}, {-0.02, 0.0025}, {-0.02, 0.005}, {-0.02, 0.0075},
    {-0.044, 0.01}, {-0.020587, 0.013708}, {-0.022292, 0.017053}, {-0.024947,0.019708},
    {-0.028292, 0.021413}, {-0.032, 0.022}, {-0.035708, 0.021413},{-0.039053,0.019708},
    {-0.041708, 0.017053}, {-0.043413,0.013708}, {-0.044, -0.022}, {-0.044, 0.006}, 
    {-0.044, 0.002}, {-0.044, -0.002}, {-0.044, -0.006}, {-0.044, -0.01}, 
    {-0.044,-0.014}, {-0.044, -0.018}, {0.028, -0.022}, {-0.0395,-0.022}, 
    {-0.035, -0.022}, {-0.0305, -0.022}, {-0.026, -0.022}, {-0.0215, -0.022},
    {-0.017, -0.022}, {-0.0125, -0.022}, {-0.008,-0.022}, {-0.0035, -0.022}, 
    {0.001, -0.022}, {0.0055, -0.022}, {0.01, -0.022}, {0.0145, -0.022},
    {0.019,-0.022}, {0.0235, -0.022}, {0.028, -0.018333}, {0.028, -0.014667}, 
    {0.028, -0.011}, {0.028, -0.0073333}, {0.028, -0.0036667}, {-0.026706, -0.010328},
    {-0.034728, -0.012831}, {0.018467, -0.012376}, {-0.033672, -0.0044266}, 
    {-0.024279,0.011578}, {0.019797, -0.0054822}, {-0.038043, -0.013453}, 
    {0.018601, -0.015411}, {-0.032133, 0.017284}, {0.022207, -0.01367}, 
    {0.02517,-0.015686}, {0.02067, -0.019352}, {0.02517, -0.019352}, 
    {0.022473,-0.0077456}, {0.021436, -0.0024283}, {0.025436, -0.006095},
    {0.025436, -0.0024283}, {-0.035176, -0.01611}, {-0.036746, -0.019366},
    {-0.041246, -0.015366}, {-0.041246, -0.019366}, {-0.014588, -0.010238}, 
    {-0.010401, -0.010522}, {-0.0059502, -0.010666}, {-0.001707, -0.01075},
    {0.0027348, -0.010777}, {0.0069474, -0.010685}, {0.011809, -0.010525}, 
    {0.015791, -0.010112}, {-0.031333, -0.011604}, {-0.034199, -0.0089465}, 
    {-0.034029, 0.0073707}, {-0.019569, -0.0096572}, {-0.023365, -0.0086418}, 
    {-0.027463, -0.0060338}, {-0.030117, -0.0044689}, {-0.036952, 0.0042677},
    {-0.03296, 0.011412}, {0.019397, -0.0083713}, {0.01274, -0.0065207}, 
    {0.004545, -0.0070253}, {-0.0039107, -0.0070327}, {-0.012341, -0.0066635}, 
    {-0.027235, -0.014212}, {-0.017628, -0.013516}, 
    {-0.0081969, -0.01424}, {0.00069536, -0.01441}, {0.0099993, -0.014277}, 
    {-0.037067, -0.0056532}, {-0.032986, -0.0011756}, {-0.033618, 0.0019697}, 
    {-0.030062, 0.0019274}, {-0.029626, 0.0091141}, {-0.020326, -0.0053632}, 
    {-0.026776, -0.0027828}, {-0.027211, 0.00041043}, {-0.026736, 0.010116}, 
    {-0.040682, 0.0058344}, {-0.04027, 0.00043337}, {-0.04027, -0.0035666},
    {-0.040797, -0.0080866}, {-0.040797, -0.012087}, {-0.025425, 0.015104},
    {-0.028425, 0.017284}, {-0.036536, 0.015541}, {-0.039536, 0.013361}, 
    {-0.040682,0.0098344}, {0.018361, -0.0030539}, {0.014361, -0.0030539}, 
    {0.010379, -0.0034667}, {0.0063788, -0.0034667}, {0.0021662, -0.0035585}, 
    {-0.0018338, -0.0035585}, {-0.0060769, -0.0034742}, {-0.010077, -0.0034742}, 
    {-0.014264, -0.0031893}, {-0.018264, -0.0031893}, {0.025037, -0.012651}, 
    {0.025037, -0.008984}, {-0.033431, -0.018744}, {-0.028931, -0.018744}, 
    {-0.024304, -0.017468}, {-0.019804, -0.017468}, {-0.014824, -0.018048}, 
    {-0.010324, -0.018048}, {-0.0058733, -0.018192}, {-0.0013733, -0.018192}, 
    {0.0030686, -0.018218}, {0.0075686, -0.018218}, {0.012431, -0.018058},
    {0.016931, -0.018058}, {-0.027843, 0.0035557}, {-0.027805,  0.0060751}, 
    {-0.022061, -0.0021739}, {-0.024557, -0.0011545}, {-0.024953, 0.0045581}, 
    {-0.022496, 0.0010194}, {-0.022496,  0.0035194}, {-0.022458, 0.0060387}, 
    {-0.022458, 0.0085387}, {-0.024915, 0.0070774}, {-0.024991, 0.0020387},
    {-0.024122, -0.0043477}, {-0.030694, 0.0050727}, {0.014861, -0.014117},
    {0.0051372, -0.014437}, {-0.0037465, -0.014383}, {-0.012647, -0.014096},
    {-0.022609,-0.012936}, {-0.031862, -0.015489}, {0.022073, -0.010635}, 
    {-0.016529, -0.0063786}, {-0.0081538, -0.0069485}, {0.00033243, -0.007117},
    {0.0087576, -0.0069335}, {0.016721, -0.0061079}, {-0.037363, 0.0096687},
    {-0.028557, 0.013155}, {-0.037594, -0.010173}, {-0.036541, -0.0011333},
    {-0.02943, -0.0012179}, {-0.030803, -0.0077199}, {-0.038491, -0.016732},
    {0.022872, -0.0048566}, {0.02234, -0.016705}};
 
  ResultShow[data, .0005, .0005, 800, {All, All}, {False, True}]
```

Yield

[image]

### Question

As can be seen from the figure,some points share the same rectangle (are not independent as I require).

So my question is *how can I modify my algorithm to achieve the effect of using least independent rectangle area to separate every point.*

Comment: I think you need Voronoi diagram with distance based on manhattan metric. Am I right?

Comment: @Kuba,Wow,When \[Delta]=-3.31,the result is very good!I hope I could understand your program and then add number to every point on the basic of yor program.

Comment: @Kuba,+1,So my dear firend,you can edit your answer!

Comment: @Kuba,Forgiving my lack of knowledge.I have never heard of `Voronoi diagram with distance based on manhattan metric.`

Comment: Me too, check the definition of Voronoi diagram and also manhattan metric. It should be clear then.

Comment: I thought @Kuba had something like this in mind: `nf = Nearest[Table[data[[i]] -> i, {i, Length@data}], DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance]; Colorize@Table[First@nf@{x, y}, {y, 0.03, -0.03, -0.0001}, {x, -0.05, 0.03, 0.0001}]` but it doesn't work that well: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T22XL.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Point[#]}, ImageSize -> 1000, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Thin,
  GridLines -> Composition[
                Map[ If[#[[2]] - #[[1]] < 10^δ, ## &[], Mean[#]] &, #, {2}] &,
                Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ # &,
                Union /@ # &,
                Transpose][#]
 ] &[data],
{δ, -5, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.However,my iedal method is `using least independent rectangle aera to separate every point.`

Answer (score 1):

I think `GridLineData` should be optimized by adding a condition as below:

> Classify the data that has been sorted by using this condition that the numerical difference is small (i.e., two data is very close to)  (classification interval is set to δ),
>   In each class of data, the minimum number of as a representative of the group(the last group must take the maximum, the reason is that  keeping all data in the interval)

So the function `GridLineData` can be rewritten as below:

**GridLineData**

```
 GridLineData[data_List, δ_, Δ_] := Block[
 {sortData, intervals, groupData, optimizeData, length, targetData, deleteData},  
 sortData = DeleteDuplicates@(Sort@data);
  intervals =
   Partition[
    Append[
      Most@Range[First@sortData, Last@sortData,δ], 
      Last@sortData], 2, 1];
  groupData =
   DeleteCases[
   Select[data, Function[i, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#], i]]] &
    /@ intervals, List[]];
  optimizeData =
   Join[{Min@First@groupData}, 
    Most@Rest@(First /@ groupData), {Max@Last@groupData}];
  length = Length@optimizeData;
  targetData =
  Append[
   Prepend[optimizeData, 2 optimizeData[[1]] - optimizeData[[2]]],
   2 optimizeData[[length]] - optimizeData[[length - 1]]];
  deleteData =
  List /@ (First /@ Select[
     Thread[List[Range[length - 1], Differences@optimizeData]],
    #[[2]] < Δ &]) + 1;
   Delete[MovingAverage[targetData, 2], deleteData]
 ]
```

**GridNumber**

```
  GridNumber[data_List, δ_, Δ_] := Block[
  {length, intervalData},
  length =
    Length@GridLineData[data, δ, Δ] - 1;
  intervalData =
  Interval /@ (Partition[
  GridLineData[data, δ, Δ], 2, 1]);
  First@Pick[Range@length, IntervalMemberQ[intervalData, #]] & /@ data
 ]
```

**Grid2DNumber**

```
 Grid2DNumber[data_List, δx_, δy_, Δx_, Δy_] := Block[
{xGridNumber, yGridNumber},
xGridNumber =
 GridNumber[data[[All, 1]], δx, Δx];
 yGridNumber =
  GridNumber[data[[All, 2]], δy, Δy];
 Thread@List[xGridNumber, yGridNumber]
]
```

**PointFinalNumber**

```
  PointFinalNumber[data_List, δx_, δy_, Δx_, Δy_] := Block[
  {length},
   length =
   Length@GridLineData[data[[All, 1]], δx, Δx] - 1;
  (#[[2]] - 1) length + #[[1]] & /@
   Grid2DNumber[
   data, δx, δy, Δx, Δy]
]
```

**GridResultShow**

```
   GridResultShow[data_List, δx_, δy_, Δx_, Δy_, imageSize_, plotRange_, axes_] :=   Block[

{xGridLineData, yGridLineData},
 xGridLineData =
   GridLineData[data[[All, 1]], δx, Δx];
 yGridLineData =
   GridLineData[data[[All, 2]], δy, Δy];
 ListPlot[
   data, GridLines -> {xGridLineData, yGridLineData},
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], Axes -> axes, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,PlotRange -> plotRange,
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.02], ImageSize -> imageSize, 
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, FontFamily -> Times, 15, Italic] & /@ {"x", "y"}),
   Epilog -> Style[
      Text @@@ Thread[
        List[
             PointFinalNumber[data, δx, δy, Δx, Δy], data]], 
          RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]
    ]
 ]
```

### Using

```
GridResultShow[data, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.001, 0.001,800, {All, All}, {False, False}]
```

[image]