# How to use multiple pure functions correctly?

Tags: pure-function

I have used *Mathematica* for two years.And usually,I can use single `pure function(#&)` rightly.However,for the use of multiple pure function,I always make all kinds of mistake.

**For example**

I want exact the number that in some interval,shown as below:

```
Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{0, 1}], #] &] 
(**==>{1})

Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{1, 4}], #] &]
(**==>{1,2,3,4})

Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{3, 4}], #] &]
(**==>{3,4})
```

So I want to combine them as below:

```
Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#]&, #] &] /@{{0, 1},{1, 4},{3, 4}}
(*{{}[{0, 1}], {}[{1, 4}], {}[{3, 4}]}*)

Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#]&, #]]& /@{{0, 1},{1, 4},{3, 4}}
(*{{}, {}, {}}*)
```

So my question is how to use **`multiple pure functions`** correctly?

Comment: In this case it would be a little clumsy to go with functional style all the way. How about making it simpler with `Table[Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[i], #] &], {i, {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}}}]`?

Comment: @Jens,+1,Good ideal.However,I want to use this case that I encounter today to improve my ability of using `multiple pure` function.[In Kuba's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52113/using-least-independent-rectangle-area-to-separate-every-point),I admire he using multiple pure function masterly!`Composition[
 Map[If[#[[2]] - #[[1]] < 10^\[Delta], ## &[], Mean[#]] &, #, {2}] &,
 Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ # &,
 Union /@ # &,
 Transpose]`

Comment: Yes, that's all possible, but it's very hard to read - perhaps more difficult to read than it is to write it... And (#&) is basically just shorthand for `Function` anyway.

Comment: @Jens,Thanks for your suggestion sincerely!Indeed,I also think it is difficult to understand code when many `#&` appear in one line code.

Comment: Just to reinforce the point in the answer below. This shows the two `#` do not clash when using `Function` as in `data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}}; Map[Select[data, #] &, (Function[i, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#], i]] & /@ intervals)]` The second `#` is bounded to the `Function` and the outer `#` does not `see` it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a way to resolve the conflict between the two different `#` instances in your construct, using [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) only:

```
Select[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
   Function[i, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#], i]]] & /@ {{0, 1}, {1, 
   4}, {3, 4}}

(* ==> {{1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative,

```
list = Range[5];

intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}};

Pick[list, #] & /@ Outer[
  IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#1], #2] &,
  intervals, list, 1]
```

> {{1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using Jens' approach -- using pure functions with named arguments. However, you can also use the following alternatives:

```
intervals = {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}};

With[{i = #}, Select[Range[5], IntervalMemberQ[Interval[i], #] &]] & /@ intervals
```

or

```
Select[Range[5], With[{i = #}, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[i], #] &]] & /@ intervals
```

or

```
(Select[Range[5],  IntervalMemberQ[i, #] & /. i -> Interval[#]]) & /@ intervals
```

to get

```
{{1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}}
```